# Redirigir a una accion or action Javascript PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mvc, poo

tengo esta duda, quiero que al hacer una validación si se cumple la condicion me muestre una alerta y me rediriga a una pagina en especifico pero como estoy trabajando en MVC debo hacer a través de una accion: el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Esto es una alerta");
    window.location.href = "archivo.php";
</script>
```

Donde dice archivo.php me gustaría colocar una acción, se que no es tan sencillo como reemplazar el nombre del archivo y colocar la acción, supongo que debo trabajar en php puro. Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Comment: deberias reemplazar la url del archivo por la ruta hacia tu accion , nose si estas usando algun framework ?

Comment: Saludos amigo, no amigo, como se dice a pedal y bomba.

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar dicha validación es bastante sencillo, solo se debe colocar la url con la acción, ejemplo:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Esto es una alerta");
    window.location.href = "www.tupagina.com/carpeta/?accion=tuaccion";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera, ya que en MVC utilizas una base_url que es la carpeta raiz de tu proyecto en este caso utilizo CodeIgniter y lo hago asi:

```
$(document).on("click",".btn-cerrar-imp", function(){

    window.location.href = base_url + "movimientos/ordenes";

});
```

Esto lo que hace es un jQuery que al darle clic en el boton con el id class btn-cerrar-imp que se encuentra en una ventana modal, me redirija a movimientos/ordenes que es mi vista.

En donde en config.php se encuentra la base url:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ventas/';
```